# Statistical test for differences in counts between groups

Tags: anova, t-test, python, group-differences

**Goal**:  Test if there is a statistical difference between `Tue` and the rest of days of the week.

**Background**: I wanted to use `ANOVA` but it analyzes the differences among group `means`. My values represent the `sum` of many `counts` for time-series data and not the `mean` value, so I am not sure what test to run.

I have the following data:

```
Mon: 221
Tue: 318
Wed: 258 
Thu: 225
Fri: 223 
Sat: 185
Sun: 129
```

**Question**:

1) How would I test if there is a statistical difference between `Tue` and the rest of days of the week?

Comment: clarification question: please explain what you mean in that the values represent a total.

Comment: Each value represents a count of the total tweets sent for a given time period. For example, from `January` through `March`, `100` tweets were sent on `Mon`in `January`; `100` tweets were sent on `Mon` in `February`, and `21` tweets were sent on `Mon` in `March`. So the total for all `Mon` from `January` through `March` is  `Mon: 221`

Comment: ¿Is is possible to examine the data based on the number of tweets per day?

Comment: What it make more sense to take the average of each of the days and running an anova instead?

Comment: yes, I think I will do that instead

Comment: If you have the counts for multiple Mondays, Tuesdays, etc., then you could run an ANOVA on that data. Or, you could look at all the Tuesday day counts vs. all non-Tuesday day counts (just a t-test). Please note that if this is count data, the ANOVA/t-test approach may not be appropriate (as the count data may violate the normality assumptions).

Comment: this is count data...if not an ANOVA/t-test, what other statistical test may be more appropriate?

Comment: If the counts are large enough that you have a nearly normal distribution, then ANOVA will be OK. If the counts are not normally distributed, then you may have to consider a different test.

Comment: These are each sums across multiple mondays, tuesday etc? Is it always the same number of days in each?

Comment: The number of days is always measured Monday-Sunday. So, 7 days per week. The number of days in month varies with the month

Comment: `Mon: 221` represents the sum across all Mondays in the time period I measured

Comment: It seems likely that your hypothesis was inspired by observing that the Tuesday count is the largest.  If that's the case, then the correct way of framing it is "test whether there is a significant difference between *the day with the largest count* and the other days."  Despite the similar phrasing, this is a very different hypothesis and the answers will be quite different. It also sounds like you are summarizing time-series data--there's evidence of positive autocorrelation--indicating this method of analysis may be underutilizing the information available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [What statistical analysis to run for count data in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205316/what-statistical-analysis-to-run-for-count-data-in-r)

```
day = c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
count = c(221, 318, 258, 225, 223, 185, 129)

#make into df
df = data.frame(day, count) 

#poisson
summary(glm(count ~ day, family=poisson))
```

**Output:**

```
Call:
glm(formula = count ~ day, family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  5.407172   0.066965  80.746  < 2e-16 ***
dayMon      -0.009009   0.094917  -0.095   0.9244    
daySat      -0.186816   0.099447  -1.879   0.0603 .  
daySun      -0.547359   0.110618  -4.948 7.49e-07 ***
dayThur      0.008929   0.094492   0.094   0.9247    
dayTues      0.354880   0.087344   4.063 4.84e-05 ***
dayWed       0.145788   0.091435   1.594   0.1108    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance:  9.4623e+01  on 6  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: -6.6613e-16  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 64.487

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information about this data set, I would calculate a confidence interval for the non-Tuesday data. Then check to see if this interval contains the value for Tuesday or not. This makes an assumption that the observed value for Tue is the population parameter...but if you have only one value, this may be your best option.